# How to pass fix variable in angular service.ts?

Tags: angular, api, angular7, angular2-services

I have an API to get user ID, name and some further details.
Now i am creating POST api to send some data and user_id.
i am calling POST service in different components and passing different values but User_id is same in every component.

**Service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

 get_user_info(){
      return this.httpClient.get(this.baseUrl + '/users/user_info', { headers: headers }); <-- getting all data
    }
  }

  send_user_preference(item) {
    console.log("Checking passed item: ",item);
    return this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl + '/users-likes',item); <--- here i need data from resource + user_id
    console.log("-------------------------");
  }
```

i don't want to send user_id from parent comp to every child component as @Import user_id, as it seems redundant because user_id is same.

I want user_id direct to POST service no matter from which component the service has been called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a `user_id` prop in your service, you can set it from any component or initialize it here itself as per your requirement.

Have your post like:

```
this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl + '/users-likes', {user_id: this.user_id, ...item})
```

Comment: how can i get this.user in service as i am getting this value from get api in some another component from where i am not even calling POST service. That is exactly where i am facing the problem to fetch that value.
Sorry for not clearing that up early.

Comment: @AnshulRiyal so, will you always be calling your `post()` after your get request is done?

Comment: on click of any item, i am calling that post service with particular item details and user_id.
Now i have different component for different types of items. i don't want to use `@Input() user_id: integer;` to get id from parent component as i have 4 component.

Comment: @AnshulRiyal Okay 1. Do you have the `id` with you in the parent component before you do clicks in the child? 2. Correct me if I am wrong, You are doing clicks in your childd component, all the children will use same id but that Id has to come from the parent and you don't want to send it to each of the children?

Comment: yes. user_id is same for the whole session. i am just passing different items from parent to child components. Child don't have user_id.
```

    <app-carousel [jeans_item]="jeans_item"></app-carousel>
    <app-global [glass_item]="glass"></app-global>
    <app-local [dress_item]="dress_item" [wood]="wood"></app-local>

  </div> . and so ON
```

Comment: @AnshulRiyal So, can't you inject your service in your parent and set the `user_id` property of the service from the parent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192417/discussion-between-anshul-riyal-and-xyz).

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`tap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) when doing the get request, store it in a variable in your service, that you can directly use in your post request. So:

```ts
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...

userId;

get_user_info() {
  return this.httpClient.get<any>(...).pipe(
    // apply your usecase, whatever property id is stored in
    tap((data) => this.userId = data.userId),
    catchError( /** error handling! **/) 
  )
}
```

Now you can use this in your request:

```ts
send_user_preference(item) {
  console.log(this.userId) // use it how you need it!
}
```

Now none of your components need to care what the user id is when making the post request.

Also a suggestion not related to issue: Please type your data to interfaces instead of using none, or `any`, also consider using error handling for your http requests.